# Concatenate N pytorch tensors (of the same shape) generated from within loop

Tags: python, loops, pytorch, scope, tensor

Tensors of the same shape are being returned from within a loop and I want to concatenate them succinctly and as pythonically / pytorchly as possible.

#### Current solution:

```
import torch

for object_id in object_ids:
    
    dataset = Dataset(object_id)

    image_tensor = dataset.get_random_image_tensor()

    if 'concatenated_image_tensors' in locals():
        concatenated_image_tensors = torch.cat((merged_image_tensors, image_tensor))
    else:
        concatenated_image_tensors = image_tensor
```

**Is there a better way?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good approach is to first append to a python *list*, then concatenate at the end the whole *list*. Otherwise you'll end up moving data around in memory each time the [`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html) is called.

```
all_img = []
for object_id in object_ids:
    dataset = Dataset(object_id)
    image_tensor = dataset.get_random_image_tensor()
    all_img.append(image_tensor)

all_img = torch.cat(all_img)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks @Ivan. I thought I tried that and got a ```TypeError``` due to the list, but must have been another mistake. Clearly ```sequence``` of ```Tensors``` in [```torch.cat```](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html) can mean a list!